# Remove item from flexbox by key UI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

There is a nice function to insertItem with the key into Flexbox in UI5.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.FlexBox%23methods/insertItem

I couldn't find any function to remove item from the flexbox by key though. In fact the documentation for removing item is not very descriptive. How can I delete an item from the Flexbox?

I'm inserting Tokens to Flexbox.

```
const hbox = new sap.m.HBox();
const key = 1;
hbox.insertItem(new sap.m.Token({
    text: text
}), key);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not key, but index of which the position where item is going to be inserted at. here is the code where we insert one item at index 0 and then remove it.

```js
sap.ui.define([
  'sap/m/Token',
  'sap/m/HBox',
  'sap/m/Text'
], function (Token, HBox) {
  const hbox = new HBox();
  hbox.insertItem(new Token({
    text: "text"
  }, 0));
  hbox.placeAt("content")

  const found = hbox.getItems()[0]
  hbox.removeItem(found)

});
```

I would like you to consider using proper MVC and not having to manipulate items in FlexBox directly.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works. My expectation was that for smth that is inserted with key, there is an option of removing it by this key too. Unfortunately I have to operate on these items directly within flexbox for my custom control. I think you saw my post of what I am trying to achieve. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796645/extend-control-with-hbox-container-and-inherited-but-customized-event

Comment: you can have a model that bind to the multiComboBox and then the values of the model will automatically bind to the hbox. this will be perfect

Comment: but how do I then display only those items that were picked from MultiComboBox? My aim is not to have the same model shared between two components, but rather to create sap.m.Token-s from the selected items in MultiComboBox. There is an option of using bound model of `selectedKeys` of  `MultiComboBox` , but the problem is that it stores only keys, not the text. And with `selectedItem`s association it's not clear to me.

Comment: is there a way to pass selectedItems from comboBox to HBox? smth like ```<drex:DropDownWithTags>
    <drex:combo>
        <MultiComboBox
            items="{
                path: 'diseases>/allDiseases',
            }"
            <core:Item key="{diseases>meshId}" text="{diseases>meshName}"/>
        </MultiComboBox>
    </drex:combo>
    <drex:tokensContainer>
        <HBox items="selectedItemsFromComboBox">
            <Item>
                <Token key="{}" text={} />
            </Item>
        </HBox>
    </drex:tokensContainer>
</drex:DropDownWithTags>```

Comment: just to illustrate my point, you just have to bind the items and the selectedKeys of the MultiComboBox and the custom control will take care of it. https://jsbin.com/puyetaq/edit?js,output

Comment: Thank you very much! I've got the idea